# How can I alias the bash 'exit' command to first check if I'm in a tmux session?

Tags: bash, tmux

For work I ssh into various servers and will do various analysis jobs from within tmux sessions. When I want to end the ssh connection, I have a bad habit of running `exit` immediately, when what I should to is `C-b d` to detach from the session and then run `exit` to close the connection.
Running exit in tmux kills the session so I'd like check if I'm in a tmux session before running exit.

I know I can use a simple `-n $TMUX` check to see if I'm in a tmux session and I've tried adding the following in my .bashrc:

`alias exit='if -n $TMUX then echo "You are in a tmux session" else exit fi'`

This doesn't work, I just get a hanging `>` prompt and I'm not sure why. I'm pretty sure part of it is that I'm running the exit command within the alias definition, so that's probably not a great circular logic there.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @svlasov's answer: it's most often recommended[*] to use functions instead of aliases -- they can be made more readable and are more flexible particularly regarding argument handling.

```bash
exit() {
    if [[ -n $TMUX ]]; then
        echo "You are in a tmux session"
    else
        builtin exit "$@"
    fi
}
```

`builtin` is required to prevent the function from invoking itself (aliases don't do this).

[*] even by [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

Comment: Be aware that _overloading_ `exit` does **not** work in Posix (or bash posix-mode). `exit` is a special built-in that will always be taken as is. Overloading by a function definition does not work!

Comment: You could use `[[ -v TMUX ]]` instead of `[[ -n $TMUX ]]`. Just testing if variable exist! His content and even knowing if they contain something doesn't matter!

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax is:

```
alias exit='if [ ! -z "$TMUX" ]; then echo "You are in a tmux session"; else exit; fi'
```

Comment: Thanks - clearly I need to do this more